# Cannot Access Views inside Included layout

Tags: android, xmlinclude

I am using an "include" layout that is part of a fragment.  Here is where I inflate the layout that includes the "include" (and below it is the layout itself):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hourly_fragment, null);
    return v;
}
```

hourly_fragment.xml

> 

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/visualization"
    style="@style/Visualization"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/visualization_with_spinner" />

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/list_fragment" />


<include
    android:id="@+id/hourly_amazon_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/amazon_details" />
```

I can access the items in the other 2 included layouts, but not from the "amazon_details" layout....any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried doing a Project > Clean? I know it's tedious, but I've regularly experienced the same thing and cleaning the project usually solves it.

Comment: cleaned it, restarted it, cleaned it again...still null views when trying to access.  Good suggestion.  next :)

Comment: Does `amazon_details` have `<merge>` as its root tag?

Comment: Hmmm, I thought that would work. I noticed you're passing null as the parent when inflating into; have you maybe tried inflating it into whatever parent your contentView is set to?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a good catch. Inflating the fragment view from onCreateView() should definitely be `inflater.inflate(R.layout.hourly_fragment, container, false);`

Comment: Nice, glad I could help! Making it an answer for others

Comment: @Cruceo Oh, sorry, I wasn't the OP. :P This may or may not fix his problem.

Comment: Well I'm just an idiot, so we'll see if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Since a Project > Clean did not solve your problem, try setting the parent to the container currently visible in your Content View:

(As you posted in your comment response:)

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.hourly_fragment, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot!  I totally overlooked a layout in the layout-large and I am testing on a tablet.  Now the views are not null, I just have to figure how to get it to show under the list.  I apologize if I wasted anyone's time...my bad and thanks for all the efforts!